# How to only SELECT part of column value by REGEXP with MySQL?

Tags: mysql, select

I have a column with values like "A001", "B002" AND "003", "004".
I would like have this result :

```
SELECT column from myTable

+--------+
| column |
+--------+
| 001    |
| 002    |
| 003    |
| 004    |
+--------+
```

Is this possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution :

```
SELECT TRIM(LEADING 'A' FROM (LEADING 'B' FROM `column`)) FROM my_table
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for the last 3 characters in your field,

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(column,-3) FROM myTable
```

Comment: Thank you for response. My exemple was not signifiant...
It could be A1000 or 1001 too !

The easiest way would be to use regular expressions, but I think it is not possible on SELECT, is it ?